# Template return by value, and pointer in cpp/h

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

In my header file I have a function

```
template<class T>
T Sum( T a, T b) const;
```

And it returns a value, so I can call

```
auto x = Sum<int>( 10, 10 );
```

But I would like to also be able to return a pointer

```
auto y = Sum<int*>(10, 10 );
```

But how can I define in the header class and in the source file to return either a pointer or a value

```
// return value
template <class T>
T Sum (T a, T b)
{
  T result;
  result = a + b;
  return result;
}

// return as a pointer
template <class T>
T* Sum (T a, T b)
{
  T result = new T();
  *result = a + b;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Why on earth would you return a pointer?

Comment: @KerrekSB because returning a value is too mainstream :P

Comment: If you really don't want to store object, why not `auto y = std::make_unique<int>(Sum(10, 10 ));` ?

Comment: note you can shorten `Sum` like `return new T(a + b);`

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, pointers are useful in c++, not sure why it is so bizarre to want to return a pointer. Maybe in my over simplified example it does not make sense, but in some cases it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No easy solution. Class templates have *partial specialization*, which allows you to specialize for all pointer types. But functions only have complete specialization. You can write

```
template <>
int* Sum<int*> (int a, int b)
{
  int result = new int();
  *result = a + b;
  return result;
}
```

Now, a *class template* and its partial specialization can have a static method, which is a viable workaround. Alternatively, use `std::enable_if` and `std::is_pointer` to define two **unrelated** `Sum<>` templates, one of which is enabled for pointers  and one which is NOT enabled for pointers.

Comment: Thanks, not exactly what I was after, but it did point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```
#include <iostream>

// We need a new erase_pointer, because std::remove_pointer does not work
template< class T > struct erase_pointer {};
template< class T > struct erase_pointer<T*> {typedef T type;};

template <class T>
T Sum (T a, T b)
{
    T result;
    result = a + b;
    return result;
}

template <class PT, class R>
PT Sum (R a, typename erase_pointer<PT>::type b)
{
    typedef typename erase_pointer<PT>::type T;
    PT result = new T();
    *result = a + b;
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    auto s1a = Sum(10,20);
    auto s1b = Sum<int>(10,20);
    auto s2 = Sum<int*>(10,20);

    std::cout << s1a << ", " << s1b << ", " << *s2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/xt2nyT

Comment: "std::remove_pointer does not work" (With SFINAE), else it is misleading. and you can do `template <class PT, class R>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer<PT>::value, PT> Sum (R a, typename std::remove_pointer<PT>::type b)`